# High Resolution Images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resize, resolution

Is it at all possible to turn a low res image of 3" x 5" inches  to a high res image of 32" x 81" inches?

Comment: Upsizing will always decrease the quality in some way.

Answer (score 3):

### No, it is not possible.

Assuming that your image is a raster and not a vector.

If it were a vector, it can be scaled indefinitely.

Comment: Well you can easily increase the resolution of an image (just resize the image). What you can’t do is increase the quality of an image

Comment: @Cai i dont know i can often increase the quality\* of images I get sent to fix. But no i can not resize images arbitrarily. \* quality is a bad word as it means different things to different people.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's asking for a miracle. If you consider that your low rez image of 3 x 5 at 75 dots per inch creates an image of 225 pixels by 375 pixels, you have very little with which to work.

Increasing the resolution to 300 dpi gives you 900 dots by 1500, which is not yet close to a low grade digital camera. Let's consider that you've started with 300 dpi.

Crank that up to 32x81 inches. That converts to about 28 dots per inch. You can find rulers with 1/32 inch markings and 28 dpi would be larger than the spacing of those markings.

On the other hand, you aren't likely to be looking at a 32 inch wide print so closely that you'll see such level of detail.

This does require that your original image begin at 300 dpi. Any number lower than that means all of the above math gets worse.

Some graphics programs will perform interpolation and/or dithering when enlarging a low resolution image. This will improve the results over raw expansion of the image.

Answer (score 0):

As other said before: no, is not possible.

A quick and dirty solution that may work for you is to print the image at it's original size with the best possible quality and scan it with high resolution (dpi).

Comment: Well, it might give it a cool artsy worn effect and camouflage pixelation, but I doubt that it will do anything good for the quality. You can actually do something similar digitally. Scale the image up which makes it blurry and apply some kind of noise to add "details" where there are none.